# Make fill translucent but keep stroke opaque in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, stroke, fill

How do I set the fill of a rectangle to be 50% opacity, but keep the stroke at full opacity? The transparency panel controls both fill and stroke. I want to set them independently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

or you can just go native way :D

Merely select the object and open the **Appearance Panel** (`Window > Appearance`) and you can *individually adjust* the opacity of *either* the fill or stroke independent of the other.

There's no call for multiple shapes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While I have no direct answer, I do have a work-around:

1)Select your shape, then go...

[image]

2) This box will pop-up, make sure you have both fill and stroke checked off. Click OK.
[image]

3) Right-click and ungroup your shape - -you should now be able to adjust fill and stroke* individually.
[image]

*Your stroke isn't actually a stroke anymore, it is now a shape!

Comment: That's very hacky. I wouldn't be able to change the stroke thickness in case I need to in the future.

Comment: Which is why it's merely a workaround. I'm sorry I can't offer you a better solution, I'm sure someone else has one though, just be patient :]

Answer (score 0):

easiest way for me: draw a box, set it to the desired transparency, set it to the side out of artboard, then draw your box, set the stroke to desired color and point, then when you set your fill color, just use the color picker (eyedropper tool) and choose the color from your previous box. You will then have your box with desired opaque stroke and your fill will be set to desired transparency. You can then delete the box that was set off to the side.