# Can I set a fill color opacity in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I found this question last asked in 2011:  [Make fill translucent but keep stroke opaque in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/make-fill-translucent-but-keep-stroke-opaque-in-illustrator)

My question is roughly the same.  I'd like to have a solid/opaque stroke line with a translucent fill color.

Has anything changed since 2011, or does this still require two separate shapes to achieve?

Comment: View the **selected answer** at that question, not the long "hack" method of 2 shapes. You can use 1 shape and just adjust opacities in the **Appearance Panel**.

Comment: Did you read the answers? I would dispute that having 2 separate shapes is a bad thing. Sure appearance panel can do this for you, but a the end of the day the two shapes is what the computer is doing under the hood just hiding it from you (you can ask it to show what it did). But the reason why its not a a bad thing is that sometimes you cant organize the layers as needed in appearances panel. So what you end up is manually building the layers. There is nothing wrong with this. Sure there is a easier way but two keyboard shorcuts and 2 clicks is not a long way, and you need to know both.

Comment: @Scott, if you'd like to claim some reputation, you did give me the answer ("no") and the solution.

Comment: I really am not concerned about rep @LibrarySeph - But it is kind of you to think of that. Honestly, if I were you, I'd merely delete this question before someone *does* post an answer. It is essentially a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: I'd thought of deleting it, but a major part of stack overflow is search-engine indexing.  Deleted questions tend not to show up, and a person asking this exact same question is unlikely to find the answer they're looking for.  It's hard to tell what will do the most good.